# How can a spirit inhabit a jade bracelet?

Tags: lockwood-and-co

In *The Empty Grave*, we see that Penelope Fittes

> has a ghostly consultant, Ezekiel, whose Source is a jade bracelet that she wears.

However, every spirit that we’ve seen is tied to a piece of its body. It’s somewhat of a fundamental tenet: Lucy’s Lurker to its skull, the spirits in the Fittes crypt to their teeth,

> Marissa Fittes to her body,

and so forth.

How does a spirit end up tied to a jade bracelet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Caveat: I only read the first two books of the series.*

### Mortal remains aren’t the only source of supernatural activity.

In the first publication of   *What Binds the Departed to Us*? Marissa Fittes proposed that :

> certain objects connected to violent deaths or other traumas might
> become ‘psychically charged’, and so act as a ‘source’ or ‘gateway’
> for supernatural activity. **Human remains, precious belongings, or
> indeed any potential object of desire might fall into this category,
> as might the exact location of a murder or accident.** *~Jonathan
> Stroud - A Whispering Skull, ch 11*

The source of the unfortunate Annabel Ward’s ghost was her necklace,  given to her by her lover:

> He indicated the small silver-glass box, which sat quietly between the
> butter and the teapot. It glittered in the sunshine; inside, the
> golden necklace could just be seen.
>
> ‘But how can it be the Source?’ I cried. ‘It should’ve been her
> bones.’
>
> He shook his head pityingly. ‘It only seemed that way because her
> ghost vanished the moment you covered her body with the silver net.
> But obviously you’d covered the necklace too, in the self-same action,
> which was more than enough to seal it up. Then, when you pinched the
> necklace—’
>
> "…"
>
> I held up my hands to silence them. ‘Yes, yes. I understand all that.
> But that’s not what I’m saying. What I mean is, the Source is whatever
> the Visitor is most attached to, isn’t it? It’s what it holds most
> dear. So surely it really ought to have been her bones.’ I reached
> out, picked up the glass case by its cord and turned it in my fingers,
> so that the pendant and spool of chain inside slid softly to and fro.
> ‘But instead it turns out to be this. This necklace is more
> significant to the spirit of Annabel Ward than her own bodily remains
> . . . Isn’t that a little odd?’
>
> ‘No different from that motorbike rider we had one time,’ George
> pointed out.
> *~Jonathan Stroud: The Screaming Staircase,  ch 12*

Of course Annie Ward was a type two,  and the biker maybe not even that, but a type one,  but probably the principle is the same: the source of a ghost is not limited to human remains.

Type threes are exceedingly rare, so we don’t know that much about them, but so far nothing indicates that they’re more choosy in selecting their sources.

Comment: Ah, yes. I’d suspected as much. So that jade bracelet had the most significance to Ezekiel…fascinating.